# Would ordering multiple IP addresses increase my adsense income?

Tags: domains, google-adsense, website-design, ip-address, webserver

Currently I manage a server housing multiple domains on one IP address.

Only one domain with relatively rich content has adsense. The remaining domains do not use adsense, and one domain consists of one page with no textual content (just an image).

Because one can find out domain names attached to an IP address, I was thinking of ordering extra IP addresses and putting the domain with adsense on its own IP and everything else on another so that google will think that the domains on the other IP address aren't part of the one with adsense on it, and therefore google will evaluate fewer pages thereby providing me with a higher income.

Am I being correct with what I mentioned or would ordering extra IP addresses and splitting the domains amongst them make no difference at all with adsense earnings?

Comment: Having one IP address or more than one will not effect Adsense. Nor do I think it will really make a difference in search which will ultimately effect Adsense. Keep in mind that Google uses past data and will still be able to cluster the sites regardless. Even if Google did not use past data, I am sure Google will still associate the sites as being on a single server using finger printing and other techniques. Regardless, it should not be a problem unless one of the sites really really sucks.

Comment: one sucks to the point where the only thing visible is an image. no other html

Comment: Yeah. I have a few old domains with cr@p on them myself. I would suspect that one site would not matter. I am sure it is *bad* domains and not normally cr@ppy sites (not being spam or something else like it) that really make a difference. I have to do something with my old domains someday. If you can do a small something with the site, that would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google analyzes content, not IP addresses. I have several clients on the same IP cause they're low income or for friends. No one gains and no one loses from that arrangement except I don't charge them for it.

Answer (score 1):

I would forget this, because buying multiple IPs to hide the fact that you have multiple domains would not be enough. Be sure to use different Adsense IDs, Affiliate IDs, Contact emails and many more. Also you should use anonymous Whois infos.

Answer (score 0):

Adsense work on the content not on the IP. If your other domains contains trash entries, it won't penalize you unless those domains got involved in scams/spams. A website/domain involve on scams/spams will be IP recorded and will be looked at by Adsense in random timeframe.

Adding a new IP will only allow you to put a dedicated IP on your Adsense domain and the nice effect on it is that when the domain DNS goes down, you can still access the website with it's dedicated IP. This is with server administration and won't directly affect Adsense on any level